# Is it possible to create a variable and expect the if statement to be about a variable within the variable?

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, variables, math

Sorry, my question is worded weirdly, I know. I'm working on a code for the trapezoidal rule. My function is `CTR(N,a,b,f)`. At one point I have to find N such that the value of another function is 4. So my code looks like this

```
for N in range (1,2000):
    if ((CTR(2*N,0,np.sqrt(np.pi/2),func3)-CTR(N,0,np.sqrt(np.pi/2),func3)) / 
        (CTR(4*N,0,np.sqrt(np.pi/2),func3)-CTR(2*N,0,np.sqrt(np.pi/2),func3)) == 4):
        print("N = ", N)
```

This wasn't so bad to type out but now I have to do this for another problem which involves me writing out variations of my CTR code 16 times. Is it possible for me to do something like this:

```
Th1 = CTR(2*N,0,np.sqrt(np.pi/2),func3)
Th2 = CTR(N,0,np.sqrt(np.pi/2),func3)
Th3 = CTR(4*N,0,np.sqrt(np.pi/2),func3)

for N in range (1,2000):
    if((Th2-Th1 / Th4 - Th2) == 4):
    print("N = ", N)
```

I figure it didn't work when I tried because there is no N in the function. However, still wondering if there's some way to simplify my code.

Comment: By *"involves me writing out variations of my CTR code 16 times"* do you mean there are other formulas involving `Th1`, `Th2`, `Th3`, ...? Or it is always `Th2-Th1 / Th4 - Th2` and you want to check if it's equal to `4` for different values of `N`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue

When defining `Th1`, `Th2`, and `Th3`, their expressions are evaluated and their value is known. Changing `N` won't anything about it, since they've already been evaluated with a value of `N` (in your second code you were indeed *supposed* to define `N` before all four operators are defined).

---

#### Possible solution

What you can do though is wrap those expressions in a function, which would receive `N` as input. I'm assuming of course that `func3` as already been defined in the current scope.

```
def Ths(N):
    Th1 = CTR(2*N, 0, np.sqrt(np.pi/2), func3)
    Th2 = CTR(N, 0, np.sqrt(np.pi/2), func3)
    Th3 = CTR(4*N, 0, np.sqrt(np.pi/2), func3)
    return Th1, Th2, Th3
```

This way you can call `Ths` with a value of `N` to compute the associated triplet `Th1(N)`, `Th2(N)`, and `Th3(N)`.

```
for N in range (1,2000):
    if ((Th1 - Th2) / (Th3 - Th1)) == 4:
        return N
```

---

#### Functional approach

It seems you are working with more than just `Th1`, `Th2` and `Th3`. Also with more than one function. In your post you showed `(Th2-Th1) / (Th4 - Th2)`. You would take a functional approach to solving this.

First define all your `Thi` as *lambda*s:

```
Th1 = lambda N: CTR(2*N, 0, np.sqrt(np.pi/2), func3)
Th2 = lambda N: CTR(N, 0, np.sqrt(np.pi/2), func3)
Th3 = lambda N: CTR(4*N, 0, np.sqrt(np.pi/2), func3)
Th4 = lambda N: CTR(2*N, 0, np.sqrt(np.pi/4), func3) # some other Thi
```

---

Then combine those operators:

```
Fc1 = lambda N: (Th1(N) - Th2(N)) / (Th3(N) - Th1(N))
Fc2 = lambda N: (Th2(N) - Th1(N)) / (Th4(N) - Th2(N))
```

If your functions all have the same shape, you could even create a helper to create these:

```
def make_func(a, b, c, d):
    return lambda N: (a(N) - b(N)) / (c(N) - d(N))
```

This way you can define `Fc1` and `Fc2` very easily with `make_fc(Th1, Th2, Th3, Th1)` and `make_fc(Th2, Th1, Th4, Th2)`. Notice how I'm not calling `Th1`, `Th2`, ... but passing `Th1`, `Th2`, ... to `make_func`.

---

Finally create a wrapper to test your functions:

```
def test(fc, N_max=2000, value=4):
   for N in range(1, N_max):
       if fc(N) == 4:
           return N
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Th4 was a typo and should've been Th3. By 16 variations I meant there are other formulas involving Th.